# Google Fonts only working for index.html for certain text

Tags: html, css, google-fonts

Google fonts is not working as intended for my website, as the font only works for [p] text on index.html. I need help fixing this to get font on all text.

I tried adding [h1], [p], and [a] to the CSS File and that did absolutely nothing.

```
Input: <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com"><link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin><link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Zen+Dots&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> + font reference css for all types of text I used
Output: Code only works for index.html <p> tags
```

Comment: Please include some code that you have tried. We can’t really help you if we don’t know what your current state is.

Answer (score 0):

In your other files you need to have included these `<link>` tags inside your `<head>` tag. Just check it in the `DevTools` in your browser.